# Image Picker and pushing image selected to a new view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to use the Camera to take a photo then pass the selected photo onto another View Controller. I use a segue to push the image to the next but it does not seem to get an image.

## pragma mark - UIImagePickerDelegate Methods

```
//delegate methode will be called after picking photo either from camera or library
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [self.collectedImageView setImage:image];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"photoArea" sender:self];
}
```

## pragma mark - Prepare for Segue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    MESSelectPhotoAreaViewController *photoAreaVC = [segue destinationViewController];

    photoAreaVC.photoImageView.image = self.collectedImageView.image;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing "`photoAreaVC.photoImageView`" is still null as the destinationViewController hasn't been fully instantiated yet.

And you can confirm this by adding this line in your "`prepareForSegue:`" method:

```
if (photoAreaVC.photoImageView == NULL)
    NSLog( @"photoImageView doesn't yet exist" );
```

You need to find a place (e.g. a "`UIImage`" property in the destination view controller, perhaps?) to temporarily stash that image until "`viewDidAppear:`" or "`viewWillAppear:`" gets called, somewhere where the "`photoImageView`" property points to a valid object.

Comment: 100% correct. I actually didnt need a UIImageView in my first instance so I changed that to an image then passed the image into the new controller image instance and updated the image view on that with viewDidAppear. Thanks

Comment: I'm having this exact problem with my app at the moment, and this answer is the best I've found so far. Although, out of interest, how would I "temporarily stash" my image, ie. what bit of code could i put where to make this work?

Comment: One temporary (or permanent) stashing place might be a "`UIImage`" property for your object.